# Jersey 2 alternative to ServletContextListener

Tags: java, jersey, stanford-nlp, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to initialize the StanfordCoreNLP at the startup of my Jersey 2 webapp.
I found out, that ServletContextListener is the way to do it but i don't have ServletContextListener in jersey 2 right?

So how can i load this code on startup of my jersey 2 webapp:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

---

Edit

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.crawler.c_api.rest.ApplicationResource</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.crawler.c_api</param-value>
        </init-param>        
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.crawler.c_api.provider.ResponseCorsFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.crawler.c_api.rest.ApplicationResource</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.crawler</groupId>
    <artifactId>C_API</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>C_API</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>C_API</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.3m</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.syncthemall</groupId>
            <artifactId>boilerpipe</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.19</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

ApplicationResource

```
    package com.crawler.c_api.rest;

import com.crawler.c_api.provider.ResponseCorsFilter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;



public class ApplicationResource extends ResourceConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = null;   


    public ApplicationResource() {
            System.out.println("iansdiansdasdasd");
        // Register resources and providers using package-scanning.
        packages("main.java.com.crawler.c_api");

        // Register my custom provider - not needed if it's in my.package.
        register(ResponseCorsFilter.class);

        // Register an instance of LoggingFilter.
        register(new LoggingFilter(LOGGER, true));

        // Enable Tracing support.
        property(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) if part of the Servlet APIs. So you can just add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But it might not be necessary. There are more ways to deploy a Jersey app aside from just a web.xml. You can extend a [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.19/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html). This will allows you to go completely xml-less even if you wanted to. Everything you configure in the web.xml, for the most part can be configured in the `ResourceConfig`.

You could even use both web.xml *and* a `ResourceConfig`. For example

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest");
        // do any other initialization here
    }
}

<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.foo.rest.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.foo.rest.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

See other deployment options [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3). There are a few different ways to deploy an Jersey app.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Do i have to do anything else so that ResourceConfig gets executed?

Comment: In the example, it is declared as the servlet-name in the web.xml, instead of the usual use of the `ServletContainer` as the servlet-class. Also don't forget to check out the link for more examples and explanations.

Comment: I think you also need to make sure to have the `jersey-container-sevlet` dependency.

Comment: Hmm - i never reach the "System.out.println" - see edit. Would be cool if you can have a look :)

Comment: Change `jersey-container-servlet-core` to `jersey-container-servlet` in the pom. Get rid the `<servlet-class>` in the web.xml

Comment: You could also get rid of all the `<init-param>`s since you are registering everything in the `ResourceConfig` class

Comment: Also another option is to completely get rid of the web.xml and just use `@ApplicationPath("/api")` on the `ResourceConfig` subclass. You have options.

Comment: In any case, make sure to have `jersey-container-servlet`